# how to overcome "name" attribute error in xhtml Strict

Tags: forms, xhtml, attributes, xhtml-1.0-strict

in my form  i have this code

```
<form action="mail.php" class="contactForm" name="cform" method="post">
```

Problem is when i validate it tells me "name" is not allowed on xhtml strict.
is there a way i can use soem thing else for this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `id` as a unique identifier instead of `name`.

Is there a particular reason that you need to set the name though? You can just remove the name declaration unless there's a reason for it.

Comment: the form doesn't work unless i use name, id will not work too

script is using this in few line to process form to mail.php---------------------------------


if ((document.cform.name.value == "")

Comment: Reference it in JS by using `document.getElementById('myID').value` etc. As for server-side checking of multiple forms, you can make a difference between the forms by giving the `<input type="submit" />` a different name in each form, and checking if it's set (`isset($_POST['form1_submit'])`), for example in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use ID.

```
<form action="mail.php" class="contactForm" id="cform" method="post">
```