# php name attribute necessary when posting data?

Tags: php, xhtml

I just started learning php yesterday, and had a question about the example code below.

```
<form action='action.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='foo' />
</form>
```

And my action.php:

```
<?php
    $foo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo']);
    echo $foo;
?>
```

So, my question is this: Right now, it seems like the only way to access html elements with php is via the "name" attribute. Is this true? Or is there another way in which to do it? I'm mainly asking because I know that attribute is deprecated in xhtml, so I'm looking for a way around that.

Thanks!

Comment: The `name` attribute is the correct way to resolve the correct form element in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean its deprecated in xhtml? name is what you are meant to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` attribute is deprecated just in `<a>` kind of elements, feel free to use it in forms: it is the the key to generate the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` attribute is not deprecated in XHTML according to W3C:

[HTML input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: Well, technically it is, but only [for some elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10). Seems like I was a bit preemptive in asking this question.

Comment: w3schools **is not** W3C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369281/how-to-overcome-name-attribute-error-in-xhtml-strict, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665890/id-and-name-attributes-of-html-4-01-and-xhtml-1

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_input, if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

In the $_POST you can get only the name and the value, you can do this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

To see better how exactly this information is available to you in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute is only deprecated on the `form` tag itself (in the context of this question, that is!)